# Interface as argument of a function - Message

Tags: java

I am trying to send a message to a company; i use an interface which contains a sendMessage() method; but i am not sure how to access this method from a different class.
I think i could potentially use anonymous classes but i am not 100% sure..

I have tried to create an anonymous class but i would have to override the sendMessage() method from the interface which i do not have access to. Would the override not destroy the interface method?

```
public interface Company {

void sendMessage(Message my_message);
//i am not able to view whats inside this method 
}
```

Message is basically a structure which contains the string message and an ID.

so

```
     Message consists of:
     -name
     -ID

      public final class Message{
      final String name = "Hello";
      final long ID = "2.000";
      }
```

I want to initialize a company using the interface.

I have an initialiseCompany method and a sendThis method here in a different class called Sender:

initialiseCompany has the interface as the argument which is where I start getting confused.

sendThis creates the message and tries to send it to the sendMessage() method in the interface.

```
public class Sender{
     public void intitaliseCompany(Company myCompany){
      //what i need to complete
     }

     public sendThis(Message my_Message){
     // here I need to send the message in my case my_Message = 'HELLO'
     String inputMessage = my_Message.name;
     //now i need to send the inputMessage to the chosen company
     //using the sendMessage() method from the interface.
     //i am not sure how to access that sendMessage method from that
     //original interface
}
```

how do i initialize the company from the interface and then access the sendMessage() interface method from a different method.

ALSO this code will not run obviously because there is no main etc.. i cant add that here because i will not be able to explain it all.

Comment: "Message is basically a structure which contains the string message and an ID." Please show the code for the `Message` class.

Comment: "_//i am not able to view whats inside this method_" That's because there is no "inside" - it is just an interface with no implementation. You have to write the implementation or use a class that has already implemented it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice done

Comment: Thanks for the update with your code. Note that there is a syntax error in `public final class Message(){`. You do not need parentheses here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yea sorry i wrote it myself right now didnt copy paste

Comment: Also, for an example, your Message class works. However, in practice, you probably don't have `final String name = "Hello";` because then every message has the same contents. I'm sure you understand that this is not very useful in a real system.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes i created that just for this example the message contents is created somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly `initialiseCompany()` just needs to initialize the company for the `Sender` object. This means that you need to add a `private Company company;` field and then set it to the correct value:

```
this.company = myCompany;
```

Then `sendThis()` should simply call `sendMessage()`:

```
this.company.sendMessage(myMessage);
```

Note: I am assuming that you rename `my_Message` to `myMessage` to conform to Java naming conventions.

Comment: alright i am done!! how did this work???? i have been sitting here for 4 hours trying to get this right!  THANK YOU. how did you think of this so quickly...? how much experience do you have???

Comment: @ElecLearn To be fair, much of my thought process was working backwards. You say you need to call `sendMessage()`, so you need something like `company.sendMessage()`. But this means you also need a `company` variable declared and initialized somewhere. Which leads to the rest of the solution.

Comment: yes I did something similar I knew I had to get company.sendMessage() but I wasn't sure how to initialize the company - I think I wasted too much time on making the anonymous class work and my brain completely didn't think of this simple solution. once again thank you.